# implementing program in c++ which output third vector by attaching other two vectors

Tags: c++, vector, integer

I am newbie in c++, and i have a problem that i need to solve, so here is the summary of my problem.
Suppose that we have X,Y,Z vectors and they have integer values, and they have size M,N, and M+N respectively. Numbers in vector X and Y have the values from the smallest to the largest number. So i have to write a program in C++ which output the third vector Z, by attaching X and Y with that order (smallest to largest). For example we have X={0,2,4} and Y={1,3,5}, then  Z should be Z={0,1,2,3,4,5} !!

Comment: Where is your program? What have you tried?

Comment: A single for loop should do.. have you tried anything at all? Or just append both vectors to vector Z and sort it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is pretty simple, if the two initial vectors are sorted: you just have to merge the two vectors together using [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge):

```
std::vector<int> x; // your X
std::vector<int> y; // your Y
std::vector<int> z;

std::merge(
    std::begin(x), std::end(x), 
    std::begin(y), std::end(y), 
    std::back_inserter(z)
);
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47da22d60103d8fc) is a live example of the algorithm above.

Comment: A merge sort should also do. Essentially the same procedure.

Comment: @Xephon, `std::merge` is the key procedure of merge sort.

Comment: @Jeffery, yes, just realized that :)